# Mongoose - updateMany

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Will updateMany take care of both attributes in criteria or it will just work with job field?

```
let criteria = {
    job: job._id,
    user: {$in: applicantIds}
}

let updatableObject = {
    interviewInvitation: true
}

await UserJob.updateMany(criteria, {$set: updatableObject})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter criteria works as an AND.  All criteria must be met.